# C++ precision - behaviour of setprecision

Tags: c++, floating-point, precision, floating-point-precision, double-precision

As I understand it the setprecision function specifies the minimal precision but when I run the following code I get only 3 numbers after the decimal point:

```
int main()
{
    double a = 123.4567890;
    double b = 123.4000000;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(5) << a << std::endl; // Udesireble 
    std::cout.setf(std::ios::fixed);
    std::cout << std::setprecision(5) << a << std::endl; // Desireble 

    std::cout << std::setprecision(5) << b << std::endl; // Udesireble
    std::cout.unsetf(std::ios::fixed);
    std::cout << std::setprecision(5) << b << std::endl; // Desireble 
    return 0;
}
```

which prints:

```
123.46      // Udesireble
123.45679   // Desireble 
123.40000   // Udesireble
123.4       // Desireble
```

Is there any way I can avoid checking the number of digits after the decimal point myself in order to know whether to set fixed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My impression is that you will need to format to `string` first, and then replace trailing zeros with spaces.

Comment: Sadly, this is the only solution that worked so far, but I was just sure that C++ might have something more elegant that I'm just not aware of.

Comment: @SadStudent  Your requirement is a bit uncommon.  The usual is to have a fixed number of decimal positions (and zero-filling :-( ).  It's very good you asked.

Answer (score 0):

For the streams, you can use two functions.
`setfill(char_type c)`, which set the character to write, to match with the number of needed character (more information [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setfill))

There is the setw(int) function, which set the width of field of the value to display. (documentation [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) )

Using these functions, you may have a solution

Comment: I don't see how can I solve it using those functions because at most they can help me add extra zeros for example in the end which I wrote I don't want I just want up to 5 digits after the point

Comment: As I mention in the example code I've tried that but then it ruins the cases where I don't want meaningless trailing zeros because it's "fixed", I'm looking for a way that does not make me check every the number of digits in every double I want to put in the stream